# TypeError: expected BaseHandler instance, got <type 'str'>

Tags: python

```
import urllib2, re, urllib

def login():
    host = "http://localhost/cms/"
    user = 'admin'
    passw = 'admin'
    error = "Login to CMS Made Simple"
    form = [
        ('username', user),
        ('password', word)]   
    target = host + "/admin/login.php"
    login_form_data = urllib.urlencode(form)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(target)
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    source = opener.open(target, login_form_data).read()
    if re.search(error, source) == None : 
        print 'FOund =>>>' + target + 'Username : ' + user + 'Password :  ' + word
    else: 
        print 'Not Found=>> ' + target + '  Username : ' + user + 'Password :  ' + word

login()
```

I'm getting this:

```
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(host)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 486, in build_opener
    opener.add_handler(h)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 322, in add_handler
    type(handler))
TypeError: expected BaseHandler instance, got <type 'str'>
```

I think the problem is here: `opener = urllib2.build_opener(target)`

But how to solve it? I tried a lot.

Comment: The error message is fairly self-explanatory. You're passing a string to `build_opener` as the first parameter, when you should be passing a `BaseHandler`. Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.build_opener) for `urllib2.build_opener`:

> handlers can be either instances of BaseHandler, or subclasses of
>   BaseHandler (in which case it must be possible to call the constructor
>   without any parameters).

You try to pass `str` instead:

```
target=host+"/admin/login.php"
... 
opener = urllib2.build_opener(target)
```

Try [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library with simplified API to fetch URLs.

Answer (score 0):

If you just remove the line, it will work; build_opener does not need arguments unless you want it to do something specific. In this instance, you may want to add a CookieProcessor if the server expects to use cookies to keep you logged in.

```
cjar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cjar)
```

Comment: Thats It . Thank you Brother ^^